# Meta question: counting bytes

Tags: discussion

Sorry if this is the wrong way to ask this...

Many languages used here have characters outside the ASCII character set, yet the headlines of answers written in such languages often say ***n* bytes**, when in fact they comprise ***n* characters** that actually need substantially more *bytes* to encode.

I don't begrudge a win based on counting *characters*, but labelling the smaller count as *bytes* is misleading.

Is there a site policy for this? If not, can one please be created?

At minimum, if an answer is going to claim "bytes", it should specify *which encoding and charset* justifies its claim.

Otherwise "bytes" should refer to a standard established by site policy; I suggest normalized UTF-8, but any fair encoding would be acceptable, including UCS-2.

If there's a better forum to raise this, please let me know and I'll move the conversation there.

Comment: This is a frequently asked question; the answer is that those languages use SBCSs: single-byte character sets. They're just custom encodings. Most languages that use these will have a reference for their SBCS in a link in the header; languages without an SBCS still must use UTF-8 or some similar encoding under site rules.

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms Thanks for migrating this to the correct forum. I will look more closely to find links to SBCS encodings for each answer. That said, it still seems like it wouldn't need a FAQ if counts were labelled as "characters" or "glyphs" or "codepoints" or similar, rather than "bytes".

Comment: Well, they are still bytes, just measured with a nonstandard encoding. You can store and run, e.g., Jelly and Vyxal programs from a file that's exactly the byte count on-disk as the header says here on CGCC. If scoring was in characters, every one of the 1114112 Unicode characters would be fair game for operators, whereas SBCS designers still need to stick to 256. (Early on, languages would use pre-existing encodings like [CP437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) to take advantage of the full 256, but that got annoying).